# Can I create a not clickable post?

Tags: posts

My landing page is displaying all posts that have been posted so far. On special occasions (e.g. holidays) I want to post a gif or picture and only a few words (e.g Happy holidays!) which is not clickable. There will be no further text, so I don't need this kind of post to get me to another page.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways but I think every needs to change your archive template (or other template which display your list). You can use some [custom field plugins](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/search/custom+field/) to add one with "Don't link do article" and set this in your template in places where you have anchors. That's a quick solution. But out-of-box Wordpress does not have any "link or not" solution.

Comment: I tried it with a custom post type but could't get the custom post type displayed along with the other posts.

Comment: I'm talking about custom fields, not custom post type :) Take a look closer to ACF (https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) or CFS (https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-suite/)

Comment: As per this answer, plus you could do it by simply setting a meta_value on the post of (say) "no_click" - this negates the requirement for something heavy like ACF.